# Replacing a column of data in text files with Linux command

Tags: linux

I have several text files whose lines are tab-delimited.
The second column contains incorrect data.
How do I change everything in the second column to a specific text string?

Answer (score 3):

```
awk ' { $2="<STRING>"; print } ' <FILENAME>
```

Comment: Beat me to it. Just trying to validate as your answer came through :-)

Comment: I think that will split on any whitespace, not just tabs.  Adding a -F"\t" might help.

Comment: How would I supply an argument to the command above.  Example, if STRING and FILENAME were the same, could I pipe the value as an argument to the command?

Comment: If you're using bash, you could use environment variables.  Like:

   export var="foo.txt"
   awk -F"\t" '{$2="'$var'"; print}' $var

Answer (score 2):

```
cat INFILE | perl -ne '$ln=$_;@x=split(/","/); @a=split(/","/, $ln,8);@b=splice(@a,0,7);  $l=join("\",\"", @b); $r=join("\",\"", splice(@x,8)); print "$l\",\"10\",\"$r"'
```

This is an example that changes the 10th column to "10". I prefer this as I don't have to count the matching parenthesis like in the sed technique.

Answer (score 1):

A simple and cheap hack:

```
 cat INFILE | sed 's/\(.*\)\t\(.*\)\t\(.*\)/\1\tREPLACEMENT\t\3/' > OUTFILE
```

testing it:

```
 echo -e 'one\ttwo\tthree\none\ttwo\tthree' | sed 's/\(.*\)\t\(.*\)\t\(.*\)/\1\tREPLACEMENT\t\3/'
```

takes in

```
 one    two three
 one    two three
```

and produces

```
 one    REPLACEMENT three
 one    REPLACEMENT three
```